# Update a package from SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm trying to update a package in Oracle, coming from SQL Server this has been confusing.

I have written a batch file that runs the *.spec* file first and the *.body* file second, but even running it manually does not work.

I use this syntax:

```
sqlplus username/password@databasename @c:\temp\myfile.spec
sqlplus username/password@databasename @c:\temp\myfile.body
```

When I go back to Sql Developer I can look at the stored procedures in the package and see that they have not been updated.

Why aren't my packages getting updated?

Comment: Do the spec & body files have a `/` ending ?

Comment: Can you execute the contents of the batch files in SQLDeveloper (cut and paste them in)?

Comment: @Jack when I cut and paste them in it works in SQL Developer, but the same file isn't working through SQL*Plus.

Comment: Can you connect to SQL*Plus ok with `sqlplus username/password@databasename`?

Comment: Yes I can connect successfully, I just can't seem to be able to apply my package (.spec and .body) changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spec and body files need to have `/` make SQL*Plus create/replace the object.

Without the `/`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST12_13 AS

PROCEDURE TEST12_13;

END;
```

---

```
STAGE@DB>@C:\TEST.PKS
  6
```

---

With the `/`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST12_13 AS

PROCEDURE TEST12_13;

END;

/
```

---

```
STAGE@DB>@C:\TEST.PKS

Package created.
```

---

In reply to your comment about passing filename as parameter, instead of passing the filename as parameter, have SQL*Plus ask you for the filename

```
    wrapper.sql

ACCEPT filename_var Prompt 'Enter filename'

@c:\temp\&filename_var
/
@c:\temp\&filename_var
/
```

Comment: When I add the / at the end SQL*Plus is not prompting me to enter a value. I did not write the package and it's fairly big. What conditions cause this to happen?

Comment: @H. Abraham what value is expected ? The standard response should be a `Package created` reply. Can you post the message being shown ? Open SQL*Plus & run `@c:\temp\myfile.spec` from the prompt.

Comment: My apologies I made a typo. I meant to say that: SQL*Plus is NOW prompting me to enter a value. I wants me to provide a value for what I assume is a variable in the package. I only wish to make changes to my package files and apply them to the database.

Comment: @H. Abraham: Run `set define off` first before running the package.

Comment: I think we are close but not yet. I works when I run it manually. I wrapped the call to the script in another file. So that I can append the / at the end without altering the package script. I was passing the file name through the command line as a parameter, however since I set "set define off" the variable &1 no longer works. Any ideas?

Comment: @H. Abraham You can have SQL*Plus ask for input. put in `ACCEPT filename_var Prompt 'Enter filename'` in your wrapper,  replace `filename_var` with the variable you plan to use. If possible edit your question and include the wrapper so that I can help you better. I've edited my answer to reflect what my comment means.

Comment: @Abraham, Also it is a safe practice to always include the file name in double quotes. @"c:\temp\myfile.spec". It is not an issue in this case, but if your file path has spaces it will lead to isssues.

Answer (score 3):

Connect to SQL*Plus with

```
sqlplus username/password@databasename
```

Then run the script from the SQL*Plus prompt:

```
set echo on
@c:\temp\myfile.spec
```

You should be able to see whats going on like this, including any error messages.